# How to generate an orthonormal matrix that is orthogonal to vector (1;...;1) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, orthogonal

I wonder how to generate matrix `A` of size `n*(n-1)` in MATLAB such that:

```
transpose(A) * ones(n,1) = zeros(n-1,1)

transpose(A) * A = eye(n-1,n-1)
```

Comment: what have you already tried ?

Comment: I have not implemented anything yet.

Comment: We want to see you try something as it helps narrow the scope of how to respond. you could also point out what parts you do know and what part(s) specifically is unknown to you. try to use code as your example

Comment: We're wondering that too.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nullspace operator exactly does this, it finds the matrix of all orthonormal vectors:

```
>> null([1;1;1;1]')
ans =
-0.50000  -0.50000  -0.50000
 0.83333  -0.16667  -0.16667
-0.16667   0.83333  -0.16667
-0.16667  -0.16667   0.83333
```

Comment: It works successfully, and thanks for your favor. However, I wonder if it is possible to randomly choose such a matrix A? That is, the calculated A be different every time I repeat the above formula.

Comment: You want A to be random? Right-multiply it with a random rotation (=orthonormal) matrix of dimension (n-1)*(n-1).

Comment: Yes it works. I Right-multiplied A with a random orthonormal mean-preserving matrix of size (n-1)*(n-1). Thanks for your favor.